# how to implement json file into javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i'm trying to implement a local  massive data json file into my javascript file i tried this but doesn't work kept return 0

the concept of this function is when i enter the lat and long it should return the grid code associated to them

```
    function lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long)
{
  let gridcode = 0;
$.getJSON('example.json',function( data ) {

  var result = data.find(x => x.lat == lat && x.long == long)
  if (result) { gridcode = result.GRIDCODE;}
});
return gridcode;
};
```

this is how my data look like

```
 [{"GRIDCODE":1765,"lat":35.916,"long":-5.401},{"GRIDCODE":1807,"lat":35.907,"long":-5.467},{"GRIDCODE":1798,"lat":35.907,"long":-5.459},{"GRIDCODE":1546,"lat":35.907,"long":-5.409},{"GRIDCODE":1667,"lat":35.907,"long":-5.401},{"GRIDCODE":1729,"lat":35.907,"long":-5.384},{"GRIDCODE":1756,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.484},{"GRIDCODE":1773,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.476},{"GRIDCODE":1828,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.467},{"GRIDCODE":1842,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.459},{"GRIDCODE":1779,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.451},{"GRIDCODE":1728,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.442},{"GRIDCODE":1773,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.434},{"GRIDCODE":1609,"lat":35.899,"long":-5.426}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `$.getJSON` is running *asynchronous*.

You need to either use a callback or [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
function lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long, done) {
  $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
    var result = data.find(x => x.lat == lat && x.long == long)

    done(result ? result.GRIDCODE : 0)
  })
}

lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long, function(gridcode) {
  // do something with gridcode
})
```

Using promises (preferred way)

```
function lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
      var result = data.find(x => x.lat == lat && x.long == long)

      if (result) {
        resolve(result.GRIDCODE)
      } else {
        reject()
      }
  })
}

lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long)
.then(gridcode => {
  // do something with gridcode
})
```

Comment: @MukeshKeshu Great! :)

Comment: `function lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
      var result = data.find(x => x.lat == lat && x.long == long)

      if (result) {
        resolve(result.GRIDCODE)
      } else {
        reject()
      }
  })
}
};
$("#Btn" ).click(function()
{
var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value,
long = document.getElementById("long").value;
var result = lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long);
$("#result").html(result);
});`

Comment: No. You can't just assign the return value to `#result` you need to use `.then` and do the assignment to `#result` there.

Comment: @MukeshKeshu any idea please

Comment: $("#Btn" ).click(function() {
var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
long = document.getElementById("long").value; 
lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long).then(result =>{
$("#result").html(result)
});

Comment: you have to set the result  from lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong() to #result only when the promise is delivered. i.e  inside "then"

Answer (score 0):

It's because the getJSON call is asynchronous. You should do Promise based implementation.